# qtip2 modal dialog not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I am using qtip2 for alert, confirm, dialogue functionality.  Now I want to  as (blockui plugin) block the view of the page until some process completes (e. ajax start etc).  For that I am using following code

```
function blockPageDialog(content, title) {

    /* 
    * mainbody is the id of the body section of html
    */
    $('#mainbody').qtip(
                {
                    content: {
                        text: '<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>'

                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'center', at: 'center', // Center it...
                        target: $(window) // ... in the window
                    },
                    show: {
                        ready: true, // Show it straight away
                        modal: {
                            on: true, // Make it modal (darken the rest of the page)...
                            blur: false, // ... but don't close the tooltip when clicked
                            escape: false //dont hide on escape button 
                        }
                    },
                    hide: true, // We'll hide it maunally

                    style: {
                        classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded qtip-dialogue', // Optional shadow...
                        widget: true //themeroller
                    },

                    events: {
                        // Hide the tooltip when any buttons in the dialogue are clicked
                        render: function (event, api) {
                            // $('button', api.elements.content).click(api.hide);

                        }
                        // Destroy the tooltip once it's hidden as we no longer need it!
                        , hide: function (event, api) { api.destroy(); }
                    }
                });
}
```

and I am calling above function as

```
blockPageDialog(imageToShowProcessing );
```

which is blocking page as expected.

Now I want to hide/destroy the blocking dialog created on completion of process (e. ajax complete) or on button click which not part of the dialog (thats why I commented code for button in dialog).

I tried following things

```
$('#mainbody').qtip('hide');

$('#mainbody').qtip('api').hide();
```

both are not working.

I am using jquery 1.9.1, qtip2 update (2.1) which solves `$.browser`  error

Please guide me to to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$('#mainbody').qtip('destroy');`

Comment: Thanks !!!!! it just works !!!! modified to  $('#mainbody').qtip('destroy'); though ..